# Is it possible to fork repository through GitHub iphone application?

Tags: iphone, github

I cannot find an utility to fork the repository through GitHub app on my apple device. Pretty basic feature, am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

You’re correct. It’s a basic feature and I’m disappointed GitHub hasn’t provided that ability.